# Should closures be used to structure code even if they are not depended on lexical scope? How about redeclaration inside loops?

Tags: javascript

2 questions:

Closures have the advantage of being able to access the outer scopes and therefore are a great tool in our toolbox.
Is it frowned upon just using them to structure the program if scoping is not needed?.

```
foo = () => {

  closure = (_)=> {
    ...
  }

  if(...){
    closure(bar);
  }else{
    closure(baz);
  }
}
```

In this case the function does not depend on the scope and could
be moved one level higher without change in functionality. Semantically it makes sense to place it there since it will only be used inside foo.

How do closures behave if they are declared inside loops? Does redeclaration hurt performance?`

```
foo.forEach( x => {

  closure = () => ... 

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it frowned upon just using them to structure the program if scoping is not needed?

There is no one way to write JavaScript code (or any other code). This part of the question calls for opinion, which is off-topic for SO. :-)

There are a couple of objective observations that can be made about doing that:

- It keeps the functions private, they can only be used in the function they're created in (assuming you don't return them out of it or assign them to variables declared in an outer scope). That could be argued as being good (for encapsulation) and as bad (limited reuse).
- Modules probably reduce the desire to do this a bit (though not entirely).

> How do closures behave if they are declared inside loops?

A couple of things I need to call out about your example relative to the question you've asked there:

1. You haven't *declared* a function at all. You've created one, via a function expression, but you haven't *declared* one. (This matters to the answer; we'll come back to it in a moment.)
2. Your example doesn't create a function in a loop, it creates it inside another function — `forEach`'s callback. That function is called several times, but it isn't a loop per se.

This code creates a function in a loop:

```
for (const value of something) {
    closure = () => {
       // ...
    };
}
```

It works just like creating a function anywhere else: A new function object is created each time, closing over the environment where it was created (in this case, the environment for each iteration of the loop). This can be handy if it's using something specific to the loop iteration (like `value` above).

*Declaring* a function in a loop looks like this:

```
for (const value of something) {
    function foo() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Never** do that in loose-mode code, only do it in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (or better yet, avoid doing it entirely). The loose-mode semantics for it aren't pretty because it wasn't specified behavior for a long time (but *was* an "allowed extension") and different implementations handled it in different ways. When TC39 specified the behavior, they could only specify a subset of situations that happened to be handled the same way across all major implementations.

The strict mode semantics for it are fairly reasonable: A new function object is created every time and the function's identifier exists only in the environment of the loop iteration. Like all function declarations, it's hoisted (to the top of the block, not the scope enclosing the loop):

```js
"use strict";

const something = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(typeof foo); // Doesn't exist here

for (const value of something) {
    foo();
    
    function foo() {
        console.log(value);
    }
}

console.log(typeof foo); // Doesn't exist here
```

> Does redeclaration hurt performance?

Not really. The JavaScript engine only has to *parse* the code once, creating the bytecode or machine code for the function, and then can reuse that bytecode or machine code when creating each of the function objects and attaching them to the environment they close over. Modern engines are **very** good at that. If you're creating millions of temporary objects, that might cause memory churn, but only worry about it if and when you have a performance problem that you've traced to a place where you've done it.

Comment: "There is no one way to write JavaScript code (or any other code). This part of the question calls for opinion, which is off-topic for SO. :-)" . I am aware, do you have a suggestion where such questions would better fit in? Is there a stack for this purpose?

Comment: @Kilian - Well, it's just one part of the question. :-) Check out https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see if you think that part might fit there. I haven't participated much there (for no good reason), so I don't know the way things work there.